# Why my Maven cant find the route to the specified jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am working with a Spring enviroment with Maven, im adding a Cucumber plug-in to BDD testing, I have specified the pom.xml with all the routes but when I try to run as Unit test I find a **`java.io.FileNotFoundException`** 
This is the full trace:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\M2_Repo\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.2\cucumber-core-1.2.2.jar (The system can not find the specified route)
at cucumber.runtime.io.ZipResourceIteratorFactory.createIterator(ZipResourceIteratorFactory.java:41) .... and so on
```

but when i visit the place where the .jar is supposed to be ... yes there it is at

> \M2_Repo\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.2\cucumber-core-1.2.2.jar

Why is my enviroment not finding the path? Should I add jar manually to maven repository?
Will I find the same problem with the next projects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `M2_HOME` set to (environment variable) ?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: Im thinking that it may be related with the %20 windows path notation in: C:\Program%20Files\. The maven download the packages but something go wrong with the path....

Comment: At the location of your jar file there might be multiple .lastUpdated files. Delete them all and then try.

Comment: try deleting the existing and building again to fetch a fresh jar. In case the existing might be corrupted.

Comment: The %20 is a url encoded blank, it wont work in file path. Whichever component does that conversion is at fault. I dont think maven does that ordinarily, so it looks more like a cucumber bug.

Comment: Do you mean your repo is under Program Files or directly on the c: drive? You might need to add `/c:/M2_Repo/` to your `localRepository` in settings.xml. (I dont think it is happy about a leading backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Seems te issue is in your local repository, I would delete it and then do a maven clean install (mvn clean install) to build modules and re-install it in myrepo, check your environment variables as well.